# Unix ACLs - After Applying, normal permissions are wrong

Tags: linux, ubuntu, access-control-list

I have a problem when using ACLs

I have one file

```
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 0 Sep  5 17:53 postfix_exporter_input.log
```

The permissions 0640 are correct and they need to stay like this. Now I want to apply an ACL, that allows a single user to read and write to that file. So I write:

```
setfacl -m u::rw,g::r,o::-,u:postfixexporter:rw postfix_exporter_input.log
```

getfacl now outputs the following, which is actually correct:

```
# file: postfix_exporter_input.log
# owner: syslog
# group: adm
user::rw-
user:postfixexporter:rw-
group::r--
mask::rw-
other::---
```

However, when I do a normal ls on that file, I get the following:

```
-rw-rw----+ 1 syslog adm 0 Sep  5 18:01 postfix_exporter_input.log
```

Why did the permissions change to group:rw ?